# What is your favorite online graphing tool?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

I'm looking for a nice, quick online graphing tool. The ability to link to, or embed the output would be handy, too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Some good options:

- [Livegap Charts](https://livegap.com/charts/)
- [Online Chart Tool](http://www.onlinecharttool.com/graph.php)
- [GraphFunc Tool](http://graph.seriesmathstudy.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I gonna try this too haha

Answer (score 30):

[desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/) It's by far the best.

Comment: It can now graph derivatives and integrals!  (though it may take a while for it to load up if the integral is complicated)

Comment: oh yeaa, agreed. I am using this since few years ago

Answer (score 20):

Well, I am not sure where you want to embed the graphs, but [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28x%29) is pretty handy for graphing. It has most of the features of Mathematica, can handle 3D functions, and fancy scaling and such. I highly recommend it.

Comment: I am using Wolfram Alpha too but is in mobile version. I subscribed it. Very handy!

Answer (score 19):

I really like [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org) as a web based graphing tool (requires Java).

Comment: I agree, it's also freeware and has a variety of applications. Great software to use for educational purposes too.

Comment: Also, GeoGebra can output TikZ code so that you can generate nice graphs in TeX which is very useful.

Comment: Geogebra is no longer Java-based. (Thank goodness!)

Comment: Oh? Never know that it is no longer Java-based! Thanks god!

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a good interactive charts without flash (plain HTML + Javascript) and found out that http://DIYcharts.com is the most handy and easy one to use, much Like google Charts.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the online tools I am using daily for plotting graphs and also graphing geometry:

1. [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com) (great usability, awesome features)
2. [Plotlux](https://www.matheretter.de/calc/plotlux) (powerful plotter, based on fooplot)
3. [Graph.tk](http://graph.tk) (fast and easy plotter)
4. [JSXGraph](https://jsxgraph.org/) (powerful tool for plots and geometry, however, you need to know javascript)
5. [Geodrafter](https://www.matheretter.de/calc/geodrafter) (graphing of simple geometric shapes)
6. [Geoservant 3D](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/en/) (graphing of simple 3D objects)
7. [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic) (powerful, comprehensive, but cannot be used commercially)
8. [Sketchometry](https://start.sketchometry.org) (geometric objects, interesting usability)

As soon as I discover new tools, I am updating my post.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I gonna try it too!

Answer (score 2):

I created a tool to plot graphics and published it several hours ago.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xD080qQVaD8&feature=youtu.be

https://github.com/burlachenkok/plotter_plusplus

To use this tool you can use desktop computer to show graphics and listen income connections over the network.

Your target project can be run anywhere in any language in any platform - to update graphics just send data over the network.

Comment: The OP said "online graphing tool".

Comment: If "online" means connect to it via network - then my tool allow todo it via talking with it via simple text protocol over TCP/IP. My project contains ready to use wrappers for python. If "online" means free web service then my tool is not about it.

Comment: But the title means "online graphing tool" though +1

Answer (score 0):

I began undergrad as a math education major. I found Desmos extremely helpful for clearly displaying graphs with a user face that was simple enough for all my students to work. Combining this display with the Windows Snipping Tool lesson plans and handouts became easier to create.

Having switched majors/graduate with a math degree and working on a masters in math with a statistics concentration I really like using R. RStudio has a beautiful output; there are a few open courses on the DataCamp website for making charts and graphs in R. It's pretty neat.

Answer (score 0):

For me I have been using [Transum](https://www.transum.org/Maths/Activity/Graph/Desmos.asp). It helps me showing quickly graph of any correct equation